# Dealing with Mandrill Webhook data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to handle Mandrill's webhook data when I get a bounce I want Mandrill to tell my app which email it was and save various data in a MySql Database.

I am working with PHP here, according to Mandrill they send a URL I give them a $_POST request with JSON data.

Normally I would json_decode() this request, but when I do so, it appears to be blank. To me the JSON looks malformed, but perhaps I need to do something else with it first?

This is what I receive in my script:

```
[mandrill_events] => 
[{\"event\":\"hard_bounce\",\"msg\":{\"ts\":1365109999,\"subject\":\"This an example webhook message\",\"email\":\"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com\",\"sender\":\"example.sender@mandrillapp.com\",\"tags\":[\"webhook-example\"],\"state\":\"bounced\",\"metadata\":{\"user_id\":111},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"_version\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"bounce_description\":\"bad_mailbox\",\"bgtools_code\":10,\"diag\":\"smtp;550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient\'s email address for typos or unnecessary spaces.\"},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"ts\":1390483382},{\"event\":\"soft_bounce\",\"msg\":{\"ts\":1365109999,\"subject\":\"This an example webhook message\",\"email\":\"example.webhook@mandrillapp.com\",\"sender\":\"example.sender@mandrillapp.com\",\"tags\":[\"webhook-example\"],\"state\":\"soft-bounced\",\"metadata\":{\"user_id\":111},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1\",\"_version\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"bounce_description\":\"mailbox_full\",\"bgtools_code\":22,\"diag\":\"smtp;552 5.2.2 Over Quota\"},\"_id\":\"exampleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1\",\"ts\":1390483382}]
```

Comment: Try running it through our tool: https://www.runscope.com/docs/request-capture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the [`magic_quotes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) option set in your server.

You can disable it, or simply remove the trailing slashes from the response and then do the `json_decode`:

```
$response = json_decode(stripslashes($_RESPONSE['mandrill_events']), true);
```

More information about stripslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Worth mentioning that, even though it's 2018, WordPress likes to slashify $_POST variables.  Back it up before calling WordPress code, or wp_unslash() it. Significantly annoying.  Although this looks like magic quotes rising from the dead, this is actually WordPress trying to help out in a broken way. Just mentioning this for Google's sake in case anyone else hits this.